# Where do I find the prerequisite files for matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, file-not-found

I've been attempting to run a jupyter notebook with matplotlib, but keep on encountering the error `FileNotFoundError: Matplotlib's TeX implementation searched for a file named 'rm-lmr10.tfm' in your texmf tree, but could not find it`.
I have tried reinstalling matplotlib and even changing python installations (I am ssh'd into my company's compute cluster and there are several preinstalled), and the bug still remains.

I was wondering where and how I could find and replace this file, as the bug sprung up one day with no change to the code, and I need access to matplotlib.

Note code wise, the piece of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
```

is sufficient to produce the error, but no error is produced otherwise until anything is plotted.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error based on what you mention, but if I were you I would try to create a conda environment (if your company allows that), and try to install what is needed there. Otherwise I think you should contact the IT of your company.